# Laravel 8 Deployment doesn't work navigation and HTTP requests getting 404

Tags: laravel, azure, deployment, laravel-8

currently, deploy a Laravel 8 project on an azure server via apache2, inside `/var/www/html/Project`. I have placed all the files inside the public on the root of the project and edited the `index.php` file's `autoload.php & app.php` according to the project path, which works, and the welcome page on URL `/` display the page correctly.

when I click on the button to navigate to another page, which displays `404` but routes are exist and working on localhost.

when submitting a post via Axios that also doesn't works which shows `404`, that works on localhost.

following is the `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is it a web server 404 or a Laravel 404? also why did you change the project structure?

Comment: is there any possibilities to deploy without changing the project structure